# How to iterate the following string in Tcl

Tags: tcl

When I run the command "set hw_targets [get_hw_targets]", I can see the content stored in hw_targest like below:

```
puts $hw_targets

localhost:3121/xilinx_tcf/Digilent/210299B4BAF8 
localhost:3121/xilinx_tcf/Digilent/210299B146EB
```

I assume the variable $hw_targets is a list or an array, but when I try to access the elements hoping to get the first one as "localhost:3121/xilinx_tcf/Digilent/210299B4BAF8" and the second one as "localhost:3121/xilinx_tcf/Digilent/210299B146EB", it would always give errors like below,

```
puts $hw_targets(0)
can't read "hw_targets(0)": variable isn't array
```

I also tried to use regex to split it, like

```
set theWords [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $hw_targets]
```

I still can't access theWords through indexing with the same error,

```
puts $theWords(0)
can't read "theWords(0)": variable isn't array
```

How can I access the contents through indexing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all: In Tcl, everything is a string. The output you provided does look neither like a list nor like an array, so it's just a string containing newlines.

You could split the variable by newlines into a list and then select them with `lindex`

```
set l [split $hw_targets "\n"]
puts [lindex $l 1]
```

Which will result in:

```
localhost:3121/xilinx_tcf/Digilent/210299B4BAF8
```

Note that the first line, i.e., index 0, is empty.

**Edit**: [Donald Fellows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78083537/5082444#comment137660976_78083658) pointed out that in this particular case, `lindex` can be used directly on the string as well, which also gets rid of the first empty element. So the following results in the same output:

```
puts [lindex $hw_targets 0]
```

Comment: In this case, just treating things as a list directly should work; the leaves look to be values that will never have problem list metacharacters in them. If that is done, the indices will start from 0.